# Plesk : Another Node.js application in the subscription already uses this application root

Tags: plesk

Another Node.js application in the subscription already uses this application root. Specify another application root that contains the document root.

I installed plesk panel on centos 2 times and ubuntu 2 times, and when I activate ode.js, I get this error.

[Plesk Node Js Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDn9c.png)

I tried with different operating systems. the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

It's a current bug which can be ignored for now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).